# Magento print store address and common inventory

Tags: magento, street-address, inventory

I have two physical stores in two different cities which sell same products, and I want to have online store too now in magento.
BUt I also want to record orders at both the physical stores in magenot and can generate reports too for each store.

Now for online store, I don't need to create multiple stores, but to manage statistics for each store i.e online store (Orders from online shop), City1 Store (orders from in city1 store), City2 Store (order from city2 store) I want to create these 3 stores with common inventory.

My questions are

1. Can we print the store address on the invoice print (different for each store) ?
2. Can we use Common inventory for these 3 stores ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on multi-store Magento - they have provided screencasts of this since 2008.